# How to troubleshoot MC emails not delivering to active subscribers

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Sometimes I feel like I don't understand Salesforce at all.

My company uses Salesforce and Marketing Cloud. I'm the one who sends emails in MC, but I'm having trouble investigating the cause of some undelivered emails. We have a handful of Salesforce campaigns created specifically to hold contacts for a series of mass emails. I added the Salesforce campaigns to the audience list when sending the latest email. After accounting for duplicates and contacts without email addresses, there were approximately **40,000** that would receive the email. But only **32,000** actually sent.

Some of these email addresses were unsubscribed, but many were marked as Active or not in the All Subscribers list in Marketing Cloud. I've looked through the reports and can't seem to find one that looks like it would shed some light on this issue. And the Salesforce Help site is not helpful.

***Why would active subscribers not receive emails? Can I even send emails to someone who is opted into email in Salesforce but who's not in the All Subscribers list in Marketing Cloud?***

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reason why a subscriber is not receiving an email. Well, assuming that the code/email template itself is okay and is not causing any error state at the parsing moment, the first thing to check if as you mention, the unsubscribed or bounce/held state.

Othe simply reason could it be if the subscriber is unsubscribed now or claimed your email as spam.

Finally, also consider there should be certain IPs to be [whitelisted](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ip_addresses_for_inclusion.htm&type=5) to avoid a deliverabilty issues among others.

You can find more details on this logic [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_bounce_mail_management.htm&type=5)